# Princess without magic goes to a magical girls' school

Tags: story-identification, anime

A princess is assigned a body guard to go to an all girl magical school with her. He then finds out that she doesn't have any so he shares some of his with her.

There's a school competition that her and her best friend are part of. Later on they are stranded alone because it was infiltrated by what I believe were assassins.

I also believe they find out that she was an illegitimate child of the king.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this?  Do you recall any specific details of the characters?  (e.g. Did the bodyguard wear a uniform?)

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is *[Assassins Pride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassins_Pride)*. Though there are some differences, and I've only read the manga. It looks like there is an anime for it that ran in 2019.

The main character is an assassin. He was tasked with finding out if a daughter of a powerful family had magic. If she didn't, he was supposed to kill her. He instead uses an experimental procedure to transfer some of his magic to her.

Later the girl is chosen to be a part of a school competition, this was done by a second assassin who was supposed to fix the first one's 'mistake' in letting the girl live. During the competition, the building they are in is sealed off from the outside world.

I do not recall if they determined who the girl was an illegitimate child of, but it was fairly certain that she was an illegitimate child.

Comment: yes thank you. I have been looking for this for a while. You're a life saver